# Restrictions of Multiple AJAX Calls?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax

Context: 
I have a javascript file, within i have an AJAX function calling a php file returning the data and performing a function with it(an sql query returning records for a set date, then plotting it on a map using the google maps API). Lets call this Data A

Question:
What i need is to be able to get the next days data and storing it in an array (Lets call it Data B) and comparing it with the first set of data(Data A). 
From my understanding i need another ajax call within this one, iv tried it but it seems i cannot get the data, i may have a misunderstanding of the core workings of ajax. For example:

```
var data_a;
var data_b;
    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: scriptday,
         data: $("#dayForm").serialize(),
         error: function( data ) {
              console.log("Error: "+ data );
         },
         success: function( json ) {
              data_a = json
                  //start of inner ajax call
                  $.ajax({
                           type: "POST",
                           url: scriptday2,
                           data: $("#dayForm").serialize(),
                           error: function( data ) {
                                console.log("Error: "+ data );
                           },
                           success: function( json ) {
                                data_b = json
                               // access data_a here
                           }
                       }    
                  });
                  //end of inner ajax call

        }    
    });
```

EDIT:
Correct way of doing this was to store inner ajax call in a function that takes data_a inside.

```
function innerAjax(data_a){
    $.ajax({
       .....
       //data_a can now be used here
    })
}
```

and to call it inside the first ajax as

```
innerAjax(data_a);
```

this way using AJAX in a synchronous way :)
thanks to those who contributed!

Comment: The second AJAX call is passing the same parameters as the first one. You said you need to get the next day's data, so you need to send different `data:` parameters.

Comment: Why don't you create a single AJAX call that returns all the data you need, instead of doing multiple calls?

Comment: I tried accessing the data outside the ajax call by setting the variable before the function but it comes out empty when i print it out underneath :/ any ideas?

Comment: Can you not get the data in one call? You are using Json so you could easily return two different data sets. `{"data-a": {"data": {....}}, "data-b": {"data": {....}}}` would look like something like that (this migth not be right, but you get the idea). If you do need to AJAX calls then Barmar is right.

Comment: well it needs to access two different php scripts, is that possible in the same call?

Comment: You're not calling two different scripts. Both are calling `scriptday`.

Comment: my bad iv altered the original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, restrictions of multiple AJAX calls do not exist, if you use async ajax (and looks like you do).

For you problem - perhaps you need to wait correctly for result of both ajax calls, to store the results and then process them.

Comment: so before the ajax call set the variable and access it when it's done? i thought i had to put it in the success function because accessing outside the ajax call altogether was not working. printing data_a/data_b after the function yielded empty variables :/